# What's the meaning and purpose of the `property` argument in clCreateContext

Tags: opencl

I'm implementing a small template app for openCL applications, and more specifically I'm creating a context right now.

I was reading through the documentation https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateContext.html

And I quote:

> Specifies a list of context property names and their corresponding values. Each property name is immediately followed by the corresponding desired value. The list is terminated with 0. properties can be NULL in which case the platform that is selected is implementation-defined. The list of supported properties is described in the table below.

And then there's the list...

I cannot figure however what is the purpose of these properties, how exactly are they used for? How does specifying these properties affect my program execution or just the design? I've seen few examples where this argument is just set to `0` or `nullptr`.

Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The `CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM` property allows you to select a particular platform ID. For `clCreateContext()` this isn't terribly useful as the platform will be implicitly selected via the device list anyway. However, for `clCreateContextFromType()` this lets you create a context for e.g. "all the GPUs in the system using the AMD implementation" (as opposed to the Intel implementation).

The other properties facilitate interoperation between OpenCL and other graphics or compute libraries such as OpenGL, DirectX, and such. So if you want to share textures between OpenCL and OpenGL, this tells your Open**CL** implementation for which Open**GL** context you will be providing texture names, which are just integer handles and non-unique across OpenGL contexts.

From a practical point of view, you pass the properties as a 0-terminated array, e.g.:

```
cl_context_properties properties[] =
  {
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, selected_platform_id,
    0 // signals end of property list
  };
cl_int error = 0;
cl_context context = clCreateContextFromType(properties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL, NULL, &error);
```

Comment: You say "select a particular platform ID". What's the difference with "clGetPlatformIDs" then?

Comment: By my last comment I meant you query for the platforms, you get an array of platforms ID and you use the one you want.

Comment: Yes, you’d list the IDs with `clGetPlatformIDs`, and when your code has decided which available platform to use, you can specify that intent with the `Cl_CONTEXT_PLATFORM` property.

Comment: It's probably the "intent" bit I'm still missing.

Comment: As in, out of the available platforms, you need to choose the one you want to use. Or you can choose an available device, which is directly bound to a specific platform, so you don't need to explicitly set the platform.